# Azure DevOps Artifacts List all Packages from Upstream Source

Tags: azure-devops

Is there a way to list down all packages from Azure DevOps Artifacts feed including from the Upstream Source to be able to inform users that a new package is available.  We own several Azure DevOps organizations and our setup is we have a source feed in one organization, then we have also created feeds to the rest of the organizations which has an upstream source pointed to the source feed.  Right now, we are replicating all packages to the other feeds by using the download [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifactspackagetypes/nuget/download%20package?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) so that users from each organizations can view the list of packages from its respective organization that it has access to.

We want to know if there's a way via the commandline or maybe even via API to list all packages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Get Packages api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifacts/artifact%20%20details/get%20packages?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to list all the packages in a feed. Below is an example to list all the packages in organization scoped feed.

```
$url = "https://feeds.dev.azure.com/{ORG}/_apis/packaging/feeds/{feedid or feedname}/packages?api-version=5.1-preview.1"

$connectionToken="{PAT}"

$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))

$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"} -Method get
```

If your feed is a Nuget type feed. You can also use `nuget list` command. For below example.

```
nuget list -Source {source url}
```

Hope above helps!

Comment: Hello Levi - Thanks for taking time to answer.  However, I'm looking for a way to get or list the packages directly from the upstream source.  Your answer is only applicable if the packages are in the feed (Cached/Pushed).

Comment: Since the upstream source is a feed in another organization, why not just call above api againt this organization to list its packages?

Comment: It's because not all users will have access to the source feed found in another organization.  Example: A user from feedA in organizationA does not have access to feedB hosted in organizationB which is the upstream source of feedA.

Comment: You can [generate a PAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page) for organizationB  and set the scope to `Packaging read`, so that the users in other organization call access to feedB from their own organization

Comment: Yes we already thought of that but it will be tedious to maintain a PAT for a lot of users.  Once PAT has expired, all of those users would need to get the PAT again.